# Where can i set the SystemParameters.ComboBoxPopupAnimationKey within windows2008 r2 server?

Tags: wpf, styles

i recently see that the combobox controltemplate has the following line:

> PopupAnimation="{DynamicResource {x:Static
>   SystemParameters.ComboBoxPopupAnimationKey}}">

so here is my question where can i set this key in window2008 or windows7?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? Do you want to change the way your ComboBoxes are animated?

Comment: yes i want to set the animation to none. and now i just wonder if this would work through any system option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can certainly turn off animations inside windows, but I think that'll affect all controls. If that's what you're asking, then go to "System Properties" (Win + Break), Advanced Tab and click Settings in the Performance section.

Answer (score 2):

As I add the same issue, I found I can change that parameter directly within App.xaml

```
<Application x:Class="WpfApplication1.App"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">
    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <PopupAnimation x:Key="{x:Static SystemParameters.ComboBoxPopupAnimationKey}">None</PopupAnimation>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```